# WPF ListBox Changing color of specific characters

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, wpf-controls, listboxitem

I would like to change foreground color of all items in ListBox of all symbols to red and color of all numbers to blue. I hope there is a simple solution in xaml or from codebehind while adding items to ListBox.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, as long as I know, there is no such universal solution. You need to focus on the specific control you are going to use.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.